# How do i make speech recognition understand spesific words i choose ? Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Header is probably not clear enough to specify my issue, sorry for that.
Im working on playing chess with speech recognition.

The issue:

```
Example: User is going to say "Rook A1 to A4" but, the speech recog thinks rook is "rogue" or "Brooklyn A1" etc.
```

How do i choose the spesific words like rook,pawn,queen etc. and make speech recog ai only understand those words ?

Current code i started with:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

while True:

    try:

        with sr.Microphone() as mic:

            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            text = text.lower()

            print(f"{text}")

    except sr.UnknownValueError():
    
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        continue
```

Comment: did you try keyword_entries? ```keyword_only_text = r.recognize_sphinx(audio, keyword_entries=[("rook",0.1),("knight",0.1),...])```

Comment: @LukasSchmid its for sure better than before, but dont understand whats the 0.1 for ? Can you clear a bit if u dont mind please ^^

Answer (score 2):

You should use `keyword_entries`. Provide them as dictionary like so `keyword_only_text = r.recognize_sphinx(audio, keyword_entries=[("rook",0.1),("knight",0.1),...])`

This feature unfortunately is not available for `recognize_google`

The scalar values decide the sensitivity to that word. If you set them to one it will map any words recorded only to your words. If set to 0.001 you will only get a slight bias towards them.

See the workings of the function at [speech_recognition/recognize_sphinx](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/f149affeac095268c22443218bf7697d515fbe5a/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L753).